# Is WCF Service on IIS7 capable of handling the server filesystem?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7, filesystems

I have a winservice, listening on an MSMQ and calling a .Net commandline process, and I would like to migrate the code associated to both (WinService and CommandLine) to a WCF Service.

The code associated to the WinService isn't a problem (I think) excepting the *MSMQ Listening* that I'm not sure how to do it from the service. (It's probable that I may still need the WinService to call the WCF Svc)

The issue I find myself ignorant is the filesystem handling CommandLine associated code.

Inside it I

- download heavy stuff from a database (>50mb)
- create directories (or *working folder* and *sub-folders*),
- build zips,
- and use the SVN app to download and/or upload stuff...
- (these among other things it does...)

After processing all, deletes the stuff remaining on the working folder of the server.

**Can I still do all that?** If I could, **Could you give me examples of filesystem handling from a WCFSvc on IIS7/IIS7.5?**

(BTW I've never done filesystem *stuff* from IIS so beside the security aspects I'm not fully aware of the drawbacks of doing this)

TIA!

@EDIT: I've chosen a WCFService because of this issue: [How to suicide a console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15487170/684646)

Comment: What is so special about accessing file system from IIS?

Comment: I don't get your point. You mean Why would I migrate to a WCF Service? If that's the question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15487170/684646 this issue would be my reason.

Comment: I don't get your point. You ask about filesystem handling - I am saying that there is nothing special about accessing filesystem from IIS compared to any other application. Your link looks completely irrelevant to your original question.

Comment: I see. so it's pretty much the same? I'm asking from my ignorance, I imagine that the working folder can't be a relative path since w3wp is the process working to attend the requests. Would that be the only difference?